# Word for an interjection made when drinking

Tags: single-word-requests, interjections

Is there a word to describe a traditional interjection (in any language) made before drinking?

Examples include:

1. *Cheers!* (English)
2. *¡Salud!* (Spanish)
3. *Prost!* (German)
4. *!לחיים* (Hebrew)

A close fit is **toast**, but this can also be used to describe any form of speech which is made before drinking, including long-winded soliloquies. I'm looking for a word that's more specific to traditional one- or two-word interjections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have only ever seen it referred to as a *toast*.

A toast may be as simple as raising a glass before you drink, or be a short comment ("L'chaim!") or, as you have pointed out, something more elaborate.

*Tribute, salute, salutation, wassail, drink* can be used, but *toast* is more popular.

Comment: If you proposed a wassail in our local, the barman probably wouldn't serve you any more drink.

Comment: I was hoping for something more specific, but thanks :)

Comment: Salute is pretty good, that'd be my next favorite.

Answer (score 1):

The only words I can think of besides toast might be **address**, **token**, or **honor**, but these aren't as good as toast - just throwing them out there as alternatives.